# Table to CSV without using download attribute as it is not supported on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, safari

I am trying to export HTML table to CSV using JQuery.
I am able to export the data to CSV with below code,Succeeded in all browsers but not able to export in **Safari(5.1.2)** browser.

I tried with **download** attribute, but came to know Safari browser doesn't support download attribute.

Please let me know if there is work around?

```
var usersCSVData = [];
usersCSVData.push('LastName ','FirstName ', 'Login ','City ','State','Location ');  

 var fileName = "UserCSVdata.csv";
 var buffer = usersCSVData.join("\n");
 var blob = new Blob([buffer], {
                    "type": "text/csv;charset=utf8;"
                });


         if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
            }
         else {
             var link = document.createElement("a");
             if (link.download !== undefined) {

                 var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                 link.setAttribute("href", url);
                 link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
                 link.style = "visibility:hidden";
                 document.body.appendChild(link);
                 link.click();
                 document.body.removeChild(link);
             }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this JavaScript library may be the solution you need:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

You will also need the blob.js dependency for Safari < 6.1